# Android Studio emulator outputs "Error: adb rejected command: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5554' not found"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I think there is something wrong with my emulator. I can't even run the simplest hello world app. Here is the error :

```
Error: adb rejected command: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

I try to uninstall and re-install the whole android studio, but it doesn't work. Also I try to install intel x86 Emulator accelerator (HAMX) many times, also doesn't work.

I am so confused. It for my senior design project.

Comment: Please run the command `adb devices` and check if the `emulator-5554` appears in the list.